# Unable to open file vcljpg.bpi in rad studio seatle

Tags: c++builder-6, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm trying to upgrade an C++ Builder 6 component package to rad studio seatle 10.

I can compile and install successfully in C++ Builder 6.

But I try project compile and install in Rad Studio C++ Builder then showing that linker error message.

> [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'VCLJPG.BPI'

The package requires in Rad Studio Seatle

[image]

Also I've checked vcljpg.bpi file exist F:\Borland\CBuilder6\Lib\Release in C++ Builder 6.

But I couldn't find this file in Rad Studio Seatle.

What' equivalent of this file on Rad Studio Seatle ?

what's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPG code is no longer in its own `vcljpg` package.  When GIF and PNG were added to the RTL years ago, they were all merged together into a new `vclimg` package.  You need to update your package's `Requires` list to refer to `vclimg.bpi` instead of vcljpg.bpi`, and then make any updates to your package's source code as needed.

Comment: thanks for reply @Remy
I found the vclimg package that here.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\lib\win32\release\vclimg.bpi
I'll try

Comment: I used vclimg instead of vcljpg.
But when I "Install" the component then showing IDE that error message **"Can't load package E:\utildb\componts\Compont2\Source\.\PictList.bpl."**
I don't understanding source of problem.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose that particular error. Your package likely has another dependency that is not being satisfied. In any case, that should be asked in a separate question. This question has been answered as asked.

Comment: I removed vcljpg from requires list.
you're right.thanks for interest @Remy